# Why isn't Django project working within pipenv?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, pipenv, virtual-environment

I'm trying to get started with Django, and a tutorial I'm following recommended I use a Python Virtual Envrionment to separate projects/dependencies and I'm trying to use pipenv. These are the steps I've taken so far:

**Creating the virtual environment**

[image]

**Installing Django**

[image]

**And then here's me trying to create a django project**

[image]

**Furthermore, `pip freeze` shows absolutely nothing in the virtual env so it's like no packages are being installed even though django installed successfully and the pipfile has:**

[image]

I'm very confused as to why the error message is coming up, I apologize as it's my first time using virtual environments. They seem really cool once you get them working.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You're not running `django-admin` from your virtual environment. Use `pipenv run django-admin ...`, or start a shell with the virtualenv activated with `pipenv shell` and then use `django-admin`. This is covered [right on the front page of the Pipenv project](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#other-commands).

Comment: Thank you!! That worked.  I'm so sorry about the images, I figured it would look cleaner that way, but you're right. I'll use text for the future. By the way, pip freeze still doesn't show the dependencies though. I don't think it matters too much but, was it the same issue there?

Comment: If you're using Pipenv there's no need to use any `pip` commands, including `pip freeze`. Don't mix `requirements.txt` and `Pipfile`. (Though if you do `pipenv run pip freeze` you should see your libraries.)